# Quadrature rule to solve definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, gaussian-integral, approximate-integration

I need to numerically approximate integral functions of the form

$g(x)=\int_0^\infty f(x)x^ae^{-b\log^2{x} -cx^2+dx}$dx
$a,b,c,d>0$

I have tried a Gauss-Laguerre quadrature after a change of variable $-y=dx$ but then appears the logarithm of a negative term. I was thinking also in a Gauss-Hermite quadrature, but it only works in the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$. 
Any hints? Any specific quadrature rule I can use? Any variable transform?

Comment: i think this highly depends on $f(x)$

Comment: @tired f(x) is going to be either $x$, $x^2$, $log_x$,$log^2_x$ or similar functions

Comment: @tired sorry, f(x) is going to be either $x$, $x^2$, $log x$,$log^2 x$ or similar functions

Comment: This highly depends on ranges for $a,b,c,d$. Please give some exact values for reference. In fact it is not hard to construct a formula for $\int_0^\infty f(x) e^{-x^2} dx$, but it would work nicely only if $f(x)$ is a polynomial (or close), but not for $f(x) = \log x$. For the latter I suggest variable change to $y = \log x$  first.

Comment: I don't have such values yet. They will be computed over some sufficient statistics of other variables in a global inference algorithm

Comment: You cannot choose one quadrature rule and expect it to perform well for every combination of $a,b,c,d$ and $f(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if d is positive the substitution y= -dx (I presume you mean the "d times x" in the exponential, not the diffential "dx".  It is not a good idea to use "d" as a constant multiplying x in an integral with respect to x!) then x will be negative so that ln(x) does not exist.  What reason do you have for making that substitution?

Comment: Sorry for that d :(

Comment: Basically, if I define $y=-dx$ then I have a $e^{-y}$ factor to apply Gauss-Laguerre quadrature